# Is there any relationship of hardness between the two problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, computability, np

Assuming F(x,y,D) is a function, and we can evaluate it in polynomial time with input x, y and D.

Consider the problem P1: With D as input, computes $(x^*,y^*)=argmax_{(x,y)}F(x,y|D)$ where x and y are two sets of variables.

Another problem P2: With y and D as input, computes $x^*=argmax_xF(x|y,D)$.

If we know P2 is NP-hard, can we infer the hardness of P1? Is P1 also NP-hard?

Comment: Please explain your notation. The statement of P2 is unclear, what does $x\mid y$ mean?

Comment: @JanJohannsen Sorry for the abused notation, F(x|y,D) means "given y and D as input, F as a function of x only";  similarly, F(x, y | D) means "given D as input, F as a function of x and y".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot infer hardness of P1. (And your question looks suspiciously close to homework.) Consider the special case where

- $D$ is an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$
- $x$ is a subset $E_x\subseteq E$
- $y$ is a non-negative integer

The function value $F(x,y,D)$

- takes the value $2$, whenever $y\ge1$;
- takes the value $1$, if $y=0$ and if $E_x$ induces a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$;
- takes the value $0$, if $y=0$ and if $E_x$ does not induce a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.

> **Fact.** The problem P1 of maximizing $F$ for a given graph $G$ is polynomially solvable.

(Just pick $E_x=\emptyset$ and $y=1$ to reach an objective value of $2$.)

> **Fact.** The problem P2 of maximizing $F$ for a given graph $G$ and a given number $y$ is NP-hard.

(By fixing $y=0$, the problem becomes the NP-hard Hamilton cycle problem.)

Comment: Many thanks to your explanation! But it is not for homework:)